# How to use a trained model to make a prediction from a given input?

Tags: python, neural-network, theano, deep-learning

I am following a [tutorial](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap6.html) with a public [code repo](https://github.com/mnielsen/neural-networks-and-deep-learning/blob/master/src/network3.py) available. I have been banging my head trying to figure out how to apply the model after it has been trained. Since the tutorial only covers the training, testing and validation, I'm not sure how to use it on new unclassified data. Here's what I've tried:

(1) Under the main class "Network" in [network3.py](https://github.com/mnielsen/neural-networks-and-deep-learning/blob/master/src/network3.py) used to construct and train networks, I added the following method on `line 182`:

```
def predict(self, input):
    self.predict = theano.function([self.x, self.y], self.layers[-1].y_out, on_unused_input='warn')
    print(self.predict(input))
```

(2) From the Python interactive console (iPython notebook), I imported the data and trained the model as usual:

```
net = Network([
        FullyConnectedLayer(n_in=59, n_out=100),
        SoftmaxLayer(n_in=100, n_out=10)], mini_batch_size)

net.SGD(training_data, 10, mini_batch_size, 0.03, validation_data, test_data)
```

(3) I then issued the command:

```
net.predict((data[0,1:], data[0,0]))
```

which caused the following error

> ValueError: ('Bad input argument to theano function with name
>   "network3.py:181"  at index 0(0-based)', 'setting an array element
>   with a sequence.')

It looks like my inputs are not defined or interpreted as I expected. The data I used for training, testing, validating and predicting are all the same format, i.e. col 0 is the classification and cols 1-59 are numerical inputs. In the code above, I just used the training data to do the prediction. I would greatly appreciate any help or advice to steer me in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: It's called `UnusedInputError`, as in "I throw an error if some of the inputs are not used". Maybe it's ok that some inputs are not used, and you can turn this error into a warning ? ("To make this error into a warning, you can ...")

Comment: @tmoreau - thanks for your advice. I've suppressed the error but now have a new error. Can you help me take a look at my edited answer?

Comment: My guess would be that this is where your error is `(data[0,1:], data[0,0])` It looks as if you are creating a tuple where the first is a list an the second is a value, depending on the underlying structure of data. I think `net.predict` should take in a array. What is the data structure you are trying to predict?